# group by query issue with count

Tags: mysql

This is some easy query but I am stuck.

Say this is sample data.

```
pid gno 
1   1   
2   1   
3   2
```

How can I count the no of records with same field gno. with mysql query

I am looking for answer 2.

Comment: Please clarify why you expect `2` as the result. There are 2 records for `gno = 1`, but 1 record for `gno = 2`. Do you want two records total returned, or the total number of distinct values for `gno`?

Comment: the total number of distinct values for gno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS gno_count, gno FROM my_table GROUP BY gno;
```

Here is more information from the [MySQL docs on GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: Why do you use `count(*)` ?

Comment: COUNT(*) will provide the number of rows in the group. You can also use other aggregate functions like AVG(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), etc.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` will provide the number of rows in the group or all table rows ?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY` will return the number of rows in the group. Here, `COUNT(*)` will return the same values as `COUNT(gno)`.

Comment: aha tnx, just using of `COUNT(*)` is impossible in your code, you should define a alias name for `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Good advice and I agree. I've added it above. Thanks.